# Combine multiple lines into single line

Tags: ruby

My file is mentioned below:

```
[Suresh
asdfala
adsfafa
sdfasdfa
asdfas
asdfasdfasd
[Sala
sdfadsf
adsfasd
asdfa
wewet
```

Based on the delimiter `"["`, I want to separate the lines. I want an output like:

```
[Suresh asdfala adsfafa sdfasdfa asdfas asdfasdfasd

[Sala sdfadsf adsfasd asdfa wewet
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do you access the file? Or, does your mentioning of a file have any relevance to the issue you are trying to raise here?

Comment: What is the logic for the extra line between the combined lines in the output?

Comment: I have a log file, that log file has multiple lines for a same log. for example an exception is raised and the log trace is multiple line for same example. I want to differentiate the all exceptions  based on the starting of the line so called "[" @sawa

Comment: @user60679 scanning a log file for certain exceptions sounds interesting and useful. But posting an obfuscated question is not going to help anyone else. Please edit your question and provide some real content or at least something that looks like an error log.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this with string replacement, using [Stirng.gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-gsub)

Just change the line breaks to nothing, and the `[` symbol to a line break and the symbol itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
s.scan(/\[[^\[]+/)
```

Gives you an array of all parts that start with `[`.

You can then process this array and replace the line breaks by spaces:

```
s.scan(/\[[^\[]+/).map { | a | a.gsub(/\n/, ' ') }
```